# How to capture reply in email service

Tags: apex-email-service

I am working on email to case.

Whenever i am sending mail to salesforce from outside, case record is created and in reply i am getting case id to that email from which i have sent email to saleforce.

What i want that i need to reply to that email which will create a record of related list case comment in case.

Please help me out how to handle reply with some example.

One more thing when i tried to reply it is sending mail to my gmail account not to salesforce.

```
global class CreateCase implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler {
global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.inboundEmail email, Messaging.InboundEnvelope env){
Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailResult();
    String caseNumber;
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile('\\d{8}+');
    Matcher m = p.matcher(email.Subject);
    while(m.find()){
        caseNumber = m.group();
    }
    if(caseNumber == null) {
        Case caseObj= new Case();
        caseObj.Subject=email.subject;
        caseObj.Description=email.plaintextbody;
        caseObj.Status='Open';  

        QueueSObject QueueID = [Select Queue.Id, Queue.Name, Queue.Type from QueueSObject WHERE 
                                Queue.Name ='Case Open Queue' Limit 1];
        caseObj.OwnerId=QueueID.Queue.Id;

        insert caseObj;

        result.message='Thanks for sending mail. Case is successfully created and the case id is:'+caseObj.Id;
    } else { //If subject contains case number create case comment instead of a new case.
        Case caseObj = [ SELECT Id, CaseNumber FROM Case WHERE CaseNumber = :caseNumber];
        CaseComment caseCommentObj = new CaseComment(ParentId = caseObj.Id, CommentBody= email.Subject +'\n'+ email.plaintextbody);
        insert caseCommentObj;
        //result.message='Thanks for sending mail. email is attached to case comment'+caseObj.Id;
    }

   return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: i am sending case id back to user who sent mail to saleforce and i need when user reply back, a record of case comment should create

Comment: Did you mean to share some code? Please edit your question to add it in.

Comment: added please help

Comment: Not a regex expert but the "+" doesn't look right: Pattern.compile('\\d{8}+');

Comment: Girbort, how to reply back to salesforce so that body of reply mail will become case comment's body field